# User Testing with onboarding

Tags: usability-testing, onboarding

Should I User Test a new feature with it's onboarding?

At the moment I do. Reason is, if I never test the onboarding part, how do I know if the execution is correct?
Secondly, if I was to conduct User testing without, then with onboarding, it takes way too long.

But I've been thinking. If I include onboarding on information that’s unnecessary, how will I ever know to strip it?

Does anyone have any good, valid resources that talk about this?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

You could preform a test without the onboarding and see where users struggle.
With this info you could make your onboarding process better.

With this new onboarding you can make a new test and see if the users understand the new feature instantly.

This way you tested your feature and the onboarding.

Answer (score 0):

If feels like you should. Sometimes complex, or even just new features have to be explained. This is called onboarding.

The secret is whether the new feature is *ultimately usable*. Ideally, this would be without any kind of explanation: 'a perfect system'. But often this is not the case, so a degree of explaining is needed to ensure the new features are usable.

Summary: your ultimate goal is to see whether the user can use the new feature. If this requires a degree of onboarding, then so be it. But you have to demonstrate the new feature is understood and usable over anything else.